# Test a variable with a regExp, and alert that returned value

Tags: javascript, regex, alert

I'm trying to alert the value of the regExp `new RegExp('(\\d)px','g');`.  The regular expression is testing the variable for a digit plus "px".  For example, if you *type* in **font-size: 14px;** I want to *alert* JUST **14px;**.  I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this correctly...

http://jsfiddle.net/6VgFc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular expression `/\d+px/g`:

```
<script>
function changeCode(){
    var field = document.getElementById("fld");
    alert(field.value.match(/\d+px/g));
}
</script>
<textarea id="fld"></textarea>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeCode();">Get</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6VgFc/2/